# WordPress - Carga distinta en navegación normal e incógnito

Tags: wordpress, nginx, cache

¡Buenos días comunidad!

Recientemente hemos instalado en nuestro servidor Nginx con PHP 7.3 un WordPress en la versión más reciente. La instalación es correcta en todo momento y los problemas surgen al aplicar una plantilla.

En la navegación normal se ve como la plantilla se ha aplicado correctamente pero al entrar en navegación de incógnito se ve todo por defecto, sin cambios.

Entre las múltiples pruebas hemos reinicado Nginx, purgado caché de WordPress y el servidor. Hemos hecho cambios dentro de la instalación y continúan los problemas.

En este servidor tenemos varias instalaciones en WordPress y no hemos tenido problemas con éstas, simplemente con estas instalaciones limpias. ¿Alguien ha tenido algún problema parecido?

Muchas gracias y un saludo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]¡

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: ¿Haz probado con otros navegadores diferentes? O tal vez tengas alguna configuración en tu servidor de PHP que te esté cacheando la página de alguna forma. Me pasó el otro día algo similar, y cuando moví la web para otro hosting se arregló el problema